# React Okta sign up responses with E0000060 error code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, okta

I am integrating okta with react using OktaService. I am using Reacts and Okta sign in widget. I am trying to integrate okta signup widget to my application but its resulting in error

```
this.oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
  logo: 'assets/images/logo.png',
  baseUrl: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
  clientId: myAppConfig.oidc.clientId,
  redirectUri: myAppConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
  authParams: {
    pkce: true,
    issuer: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer,
    scopes: myAppConfig.oidc.scopes,
  },
  authClient: oktaAuth,
  features: {
    registration: true
  });
```

When I hit the signup button from okta widget there is an API call happening HTTP GET request to https://dev-XXX.okta.com/api/v1/registration/form responses with E0000060 error code.

But I get 501 error with below error code

```
{
  "errorCode": "E0000060",
  "errorSummary": "Unsupported operation.",
  "errorLink": "E0000060",
  "errorId": "oaeFIcE87d5SxSNJ9Z19tIomQ",
  "errorCauses": [ ]
}
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Is registration enabled in your tenant?

Comment: Where to do that can you help me with that?

Comment: In Okta UI `Directory -> Self-Service registration`

Comment: I dont have option of self service registeration in okta

Comment: Then you can't use it in the widget, until you enable it in the system settings

Comment: Is there a way I can get self-service registeration  menu in OKta? Do I have to enable it from somewhere

Comment: A user with admin privileges needs to enable it in Okta going to the path I showed you above. You may want to read Okta documentation about this feature https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/set-up-self-service-registration/main/